# Why my animation keeps on last state?

Tags: android

I want a blinking text, from alpha 0.3 to alpha 1, the thing works good, but when I do anim.cancel() the text statys in alpha 0.3, I want to return to full opaque. I've tried with setFillAfter and setFillBefore with no success. My question is why my animation keeps on last state?

```
time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.3f, 1.0f);
anim.setDuration(100);
anim.setStartOffset(100);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

time.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText );

Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.3f, 1.0f);
anim.setDuration(100);
anim.setStartOffset(100);
anim.setFillAfter(false);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
myText.startAnimation(anim);
```

And when cancel :

```
myText.setVisibility(View.INVISBLE); // That's for your case, if you want to set alpha 1 - set (View.VISIBLE);
anim.cancel();
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this doesn't work, sometimes my anim keeps on 0.3f of alpha after calling cancel and what I want is to stay at full 1.0f...